# Iterator pattern, how to make it generic?

Tags: c#

I have a iterator pattern. But I want to make it generic. So that you can have strings and numbers. Because now you only can put strings in the list items.

So I have this:

```
 public  interface IIterator< out T>
    {
        void First();
        T Next();
        bool IsDone();
        T CurrentItem();
    }

    public interface IAggregate< out T>
    {
        IIterator <T> CreateIterator();
    }
}
```

```
 public class Science : IAggregate<T>
    {

        private LinkedList<string> Subjects;
        public Science()
        {
            Subjects = new LinkedList<string>();
            Subjects.AddFirst("Maths");
            Subjects.AddFirst("Comp. Sc.");
            Subjects.AddFirst(99);// So this of course fails
        }

        public IIterator<T> CreateIterator()
        {
            return new ScienceIterator<T>(Subjects);
        }

    }
```

```
public class ScienceIterator : IIterator
    {    
        private System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<string> Subjects;
        private int position;
        public ScienceIterator(LinkedList<string> subjects)
        {
            this.Subjects = subjects;
            position = 0;
        }
        public void First()
        {
            position = 0;
        }
        public string Next()
        {
            return Subjects.ElementAt(position++);
        }
        public bool IsDone()
        {
            if (position < Subjects.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public string CurrentItem()
        {
            return Subjects.ElementAt(position);
        }

    }
```

So my question is, is this possible in the default C# collection? Or you have to make your own LinkedList?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you reinventing `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable`?

Comment: By the way it doesn't make sense to implement `Next()` for `LinkedList` using `ElementAt`. It's probably `O(n)` complexity

Comment: Just for learning the Iterator pattern. But I only see examples with fixed data. But of course will be nice to have a generic one. So that you can have strings or ints, or doubles

Comment: As Sweeper said you are looking for the IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerator<T> interfaces and their implementations. If you want you can take a look at the source code https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs and see how this pattern has been implemented in c#

Comment: Generics don't suddenly allow you to add both `int` and `string` items to the same list, that's not how generics work. Generics allow you to define common functionality independent of 1 or more types. But when you instantiate a generic class you have to provide that type and for that instance that type is then set. What you want could be done with `LinkedList<object>` (since both `int` and `string` inherit from `object`), however the need for structures like that could be an indicator of bad design.